# Allowing longer usernames in JSQMessagesViewController

Tags: ios, swift, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I have incorporated JSQMessagesViewController into my app. At present, reviewing the settings for the user name bubbles:

```
const CGFloat kJSQMessagesCollectionViewCellLabelHeightDefault = 20.0f;
const CGFloat kJSQMessagesCollectionViewAvatarSizeDefault = 30.0f;
```

Which allows for 3 spaces for user initials as:

[image]

I wish to allow for longer usernames, like 6-10 characters. 
How can the cell label be wrapped around the text of the user name dynamically given the length of the name?

Answer (score 0):

That is the avatar bubble which is showing the initials of the user there username is normally shown above the message out side of the bubble. So there are no methods for supporting that functionality but you could make your own AvatarImage view that is dynamic but I think you will run into many problems with the bubbles resizing. Hope this helps.